Calculating percentages from xtabs by three variables
I have these variables:

language group:  Greek speaking people (N=34), Romanian speaking people (N=15), Russian speaking people (N=16)

sentence type: 12 different Greek sentence types
responses: No Aspect, Perfective, Imperfective


Each participant completed at least 6 examples of each sentence type (in total 96 sentences each).
I would like to calculate the percentages of the 3 choices for each group for each sentence type.
The data were gathered to a table I created in calc. I saved it as .csv file and I imported it in R.
I have created three-way xtabs. Below it is shown a part of the xtab for one sentence type:
three_way3 <- xtabs(~language + response_aspect + sentence type, data=teliko_eikones)
addmargins(three_way3, 2)

 sentence type = while

      response_aspect
Language No Aspect Imperfective     Perfective      Sum
    GR   9           397           2        408
    RO   9           170           1        180
    RU   7          183            2        192

I would like to do something like that. I don’t know how to transform the raw frequencies to percentages for each sentence type.
      response_aspect
Language No Aspect Imperfective     Perfective      Sum
    GR   2.2          97.3             0.4         100
    RO   0           100           0        100
    RU   0          0              100      100


Already tried proportions(three_way3)?

I tried it but it does not make sense

@Ana I'm not sure what you mean it does not make sense, but possibly your confusion is because proportions with no margin argument gives you the proportion across the entire dataframe. It looks like you want just the proportion of responses within each language, so by-row, so you need to set proportions(three_way3, margin=1) as @jay.sf noted in their answer.

Also you probably don't want to name your sentence type "while", since while is a meaningful word in R. At the least, presumably you want to enclose it in quotes to denote that you mean the string "while": sentence_type = "while" or better: sentence_type = "while_sent"

You can easily apply proportions() on xtabs output.
> xtabs(cbind(ncases, ncontrols) ~ agegp + alcgp, data = dat) |> proportions()
, ,  = ncases

       alcgp
agegp     0-39g/day       40-79      80-119        120+
  25-34 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.003174603
  35-44 0.003174603 0.012698413 0.000000000 0.012698413
  45-54 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
  55-64 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
  65-74 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
  75+   0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000

, ,  = ncontrols

       alcgp
agegp     0-39g/day       40-79      80-119        120+
  25-34 0.193650794 0.142857143 0.015873016 0.012698413
  35-44 0.279365079 0.241269841 0.063492063 0.019047619
  45-54 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
  55-64 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
  65-74 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000

Note, that you can set specific margins,
proportions(x, margin = NULL)

where 1 denotes rows, 2 columns, and 1:2 both. Read the docs ?proportions.

Data:
> dat <- subset(esoph, agegp %in% c('25-34', '35-44'))

